# Generation sample using kernel density estimates in r

Tags: r, random

I need generate sample from existing data using kernel density estimates in R. In my data missing negative values (and can not be), but in generate sample negative values present.

```
library(ks)
set.seed(1)
par(mfrow=c(2,1))

x<-rlnorm(100)
hist(x, col="red", freq=F)

y <- rkde(fhat=kde(x=x, h=hpi(x)), n=100)
hist(y, col="green", freq=F)
```

How to limit the range of the KDE and generated sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rkde` pas a `positive` argument:

```
y <- rkde(
  fhat = kde(x=x, h=hpi(x)), 
  n    = 100, 
  positive = TRUE
)
```

An alternative would be to transform the data (e.g., with a logarithm) before the estimation,
to make it unconstrained, and transform it back after the random number generation.

```
x2 <- log(x)
y2 <- rkde(fhat=kde(x=x2, h=hpi(x2)), n=100)
y <- exp(y2)
hist(y, col="green", freq=F)
```

Comment: Thank you! You may suggest other variants of transform?

Comment: For positive, unbounded values, the logarithm is usually sufficient.
For positive values, with a non-skewed distribution, you could try something like `log(exp(x)-1)` (it is linear away from zero).
For bounded values, if you know the bounds, you can use a logistic transform.
If you want something more taylored to your data, you could look at the (gaussian) quantile-quantile plot of your data: you want a function that looks like it, e.g.,
`n <- 100; x <- rlnorm(n); i <- order(x); plot(x[i],qnorm(ppoints(n))); curve(log(x),add=T, lwd=3)`.

Comment: can you show how to generate random numbers using the quantile-quantile plot?

Comment: You would just choose a function `f` so that 
`plot(x[order(x)],f(ppoints(length(x))))` 
looks like a line `abline(0,1)`, 
and you would then sample as 
`f(runif(N))`.
For instance, 
`f <- approxfun(ppoints(n),x[order(x)],rule=2)` would do --
but it is not very smooth and does not produce realistic tails.

Answer (score 2):

If you can accept a density estimate that is not a KDE then look at the logspline package.  This is a different way to estimate density estimates and there are arguments to set lower (and/or upper) bounds so that the resulting estimate will not go beyond the bound and makes sense near the bound.

Here is a basic example:

```
set.seed(1)
x<-rlnorm(100)
hist(x, prob=TRUE)

lines(density(x), col='red')

library(ks)
tmp <- kde(x, hpi(x))
lines(tmp$eval.points, tmp$estimate, col='green')

library(logspline)
lsfit <- logspline(x, lbound=0)
curve( dlogspline(x,lsfit), add=TRUE, col='blue' )

curve( dlnorm, add=TRUE, col='orange' )
```

[image]

You can generate new data points from the fitted density using the `rlogspline` function and there are also `plogspline` and `qlogspline` functions.

Comment: Can you show example how to solve the same task using `logspline` package?

Comment: @Andy, I added an example.

Comment: Can you recommend a free textbook about `logspline` methodology?

Comment: @Andy, I don't know of any free, or otherwise, texts that discuss this (but I have not really looked).  The main references are the help pages and the articles that they reference.